# How should SharePoint developers work with the graphics designer on their projects?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

The graphics designers that I've worked with on SharePoint projects don't know/understand a lot of SharePoint. Particularly they don't know SharePoint Designer which is basically required for developing publishing sites.

To get around this, I've found the following workflow typically eventuates:

1. Use a web browser to save off a copy of 'major' pages in the site.
2. Send copy to designer.
3. Designer makes changes and sends updated files back.
4. Developer performs a diff between the original and changed copy and incorporates changes to CSS and HTML into master pages and page layouts.
5. Find problems, restart from step 1.

There are problems with this such as:

- The designer doesn't know that some of the changes they make cannot be easily reflected in SharePoint. This is due to control renderings that can't easily be altered.
- Some dynamic parts of the SharePoint site don't work/behave as they should when saving pages from the web browser.
- Some design work needs to be done by the developer in order to incorporate the changes.

What are your recommendations for working with a CSS/graphic designer on SharePoint sites to get speedy, accurate results?

Comment: Actually SharePointDesigner is not required for developing publishing sites.

Comment: That's true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452113/

Answer (score 2):

I think your process is nearly as good as it can be.  Without the designer knowing sharepoint all you can do is encourage them to make as many changes in css as much as possible.  (then do your diff and apply it).

With ASP.Net and Sharepoint you are limited to how the markup can change if you wish to take advantage of certain components.

It's possible that you could convince the designer to use Expression Blend.  But most likely unless they have development experience or you are willing to train them somewhat then there will have to be some developer engagement.

I trained my designer to use Visual Studio and it's made my life a great deal easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that your list should start with:

#0. Ask the designer ideally what markup they would like for the page

While some of their requests may be impossible, as you say, due to control rendering, it will mean that when the page comes to them for design they will have fewer instances where they want to change the markup.

Also, for saving pages fron the web browser try using the [save complete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4723) firefox extension

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having the Designers use SharePoint Designer to work with the markup in a sandbox environment.  Then when they are happy with the design to turn it over to the development team for implementation in SharePoint solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is very good discussion of how developer/designer interaction can work best in [this SharePoint Magazine article](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/sharepoints-branding-limitations-part-1) by Diantha van Marion.